# error on airflow webserver based on postgres

Tags: postgresql, docker-compose, airflow

Basically, I want to build the docker-airflow:

I have the Dockerfile like:

```
FROM puckel/docker-airflow:1.10.6
COPY ./airflow_home/airflow.cfg /usr/local/airflow/airflow.cfg
...
```

I have the docker-compose.yml like:

```
version: "3.4"
services:
    postgres:
        image: "postgres:9.6"
        container_name: "postgres"
        environment:
            - POSTGRES_USER=airflow
            - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=airflow
            - POSTGRES_DB=airflow
        ports:
            - "5432:5432"
        volumes:
            - './data/postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data'
    # comment initdb after you will have use it at first run
    # set the client and processed log types here
    initdb:
        build: .
        entrypoint: airflow initdb
        entrypoint:
            ['python3', '/usr/local/airflow/__init__.py', '-C', '$Client', '-T', '$Types']
        volumes:
            - './airflow_home/packages:/usr/local/airflow/packages'
        depends_on:
            - postgres
```

And there is no other airflow library in the requirements.txt.

I always got the error when I did the:

```
docker-compose up webserver
```

The error is:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable) relation "connection" does not exist
webserver_1  | LINE 2: FROM connection GROUP BY connection.conn_id
```

The "xxx" include **log** as well.

I originally thought the error would come from the different versions. But I make sure the version has been confirmed right. I used the airflow.cfg comes from the same version and modified the sql_connection with Postgres. The database in Postgres has also been created. Does anyone know how to fix that?

Comment: I'm unclear why do you need the initdb section? the puckel docker will run initdb on startup. Also, you didn't include the airflow part in the posted snippet .
It seems like initdb didn't run properly, checkout the logs of the started airflow

Comment: cuz I need to initialize some parameters for the following processes. I used to test well. The **postgres** and **initdb** all run successfully. I will attach the logs soon

Comment: I'd let the airflow image run the initdb part. Most params to airflow can be configured using environment variables.

Comment: Thanks for your opinions. Maybe I will give it a go. But now I do not think the problem is on **initdb**.

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason.
Cuz I used two entrypoints in **initdb** part. It will overwrite the original init script inside the docker. When I delete the entrypoint:

```
['python3', '/usr/local/airflow/__init__.py', '-C', '$Client', '-T', '$Types']
```

It works now.

Comment: I would recommend if you want to execute the command in docker. Better use CMD in Dockerfile. It saves a lot of time to fix the bug brought by the arguments